# Laravel - Trying to migrate a new table I have created but VS is trying to migrate a table that has already been migrated?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a table 'create_courses_table' but when I try to migrate this new table, I'm getting the error below from a previous table i have already migrated:

```
Migrating: 2020_03_04_141200_create_role_user_pivot_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'role_user' already exists (SQL: create table `role_user` (`user_id` int unsigned not null, `role_id` int unsigned not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

      +9 vendor frames 
  10  database/migrations/2020_03_04_141200_create_role_user_pivot_table.php:22
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("create")

      +22 vendor frames 
  33  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I assume there is an error with my PivotTable? I'm not quite sure what I have done wrong. The code for it is below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRoleUserPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you originally created your database? Did you run migrations every time, or did you "restore" it with the database dump file?

Comment: `role_user` table is already exists

Comment: @zlatan I migrated it yesterday on its own, an error was thrown referring to an integrity constraint when i created it but the table still migrated in the DB. Could this be related?

Comment: It definitely could be the case. Check if your `migrations` table in your database has `2020_03_04_141200_create_role_user_pivot_table` migration record. If it's there, it means it migrated already. Laravel stores previous migrations in that table, in order to keep track of what has been already migrated, and if there's a duplicate migration record, it could throw such an error.

Comment: @zlatan i have checked my migrations table in my DB and role_user does not exist.. however it is in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on your question I assume that something went wrong in storing the migration in the migration table.

Run the following query on your database. Should it return 0, proceed with my answer.
Should it return 1 (or even more), please ignore my answer, the error is somewhere else:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM migrations WHERE migration = '2020_03_04_141200_create_role_user_pivot_table';
```

To fix this, you could add the migration manually to the table:

Just add a new tuple in the table called `migrations`, with the filename (without `.php`, ergo `2020_03_04_141200_create_role_user_pivot_table`) in the `migration` column and a `batch`-number that is one higher than your highest value in the table.

Ergo: Do this:

Get the incremented batch number:

```
SELECT MAX(batch)+1 FROM migrations
```

And then insert your migration manually (replace `42` with the result of the previous query):

```
INSERT INTO migrations (migration, batch)
VALUES ('2020_03_04_141200_create_role_user_pivot_table', 42)
```